# Symfony2 security path pattern not working

Tags: php, security, symfony, saml, shibboleth

I've implemented the [SimpleSamlPhpBundle](https://github.com/saxid/SimplesamlphpBundle) in order to authenticate a user on my Symfony application via SAML/Shibboleth.

I modified my `security.yml` file as follows:

```
security:
    providers:
        simplesaml:
            id: saxid_user_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        saml:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            stateless: true
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: simplesamlphp.authenticator
                provider: simplesaml
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                success_handler: simplesamlphp.logout_handler

    access_control:
        # Make imprint accessible for anonymous access
        - { path: ^/imprint$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

As I have an imprint that I want to make accessible for anonymous users, I added the according line to the `access_control` section.

But this doesn't take effect, if I call `example.com/imprint` it redirects to the SimpleSAMLphp identity discovery page. Is my pattern wrong? I also tried without the trailing `$` character, which didn't help.

Comment: are there any entries above your imprint entry?

Comment: No, there is no other entry. Is that required?

Comment: no, it's just that, similar to routing, the first rule that matches is taken by symfony, the rest is ignored

Comment: Okay, so the lines as above are fine per se?

Comment: per se it is correct. I guess that at least one other entry comes after the imprint one. Try to check your routing, maybe you have some kind of fallback route, or a redirect on non-existent routes.

Comment: No, there is no other line in the `access_control` section. I modified my question accordingly in order to clarify the contents of my `security.yml`